# Trouble with goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I am having trouble understanding channels and goroutines. What I am trying to do is, to continue "paging" until there are no more results(`len(matches.Matches) == 0`). Instead of breaking out of the infinite loop, my `page` values run well into the 100000.

```
func main() {
    results := make(chan []*shodan.HostData)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup


    shodanClient := authorizeShodanApi("redacted")

    page := 0
    for {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            matches, _ := shodanClient.GetHostsForQuery(&shodan.HostQueryOptions{
                Query: "country:AL port:8080 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' 'http server 1.0'",
                Page: page,
            })
            defer wg.Done()
            if len(matches.Matches) == 0{
                fmt.Println("DONE")
                return
            }
            results <- matches.Matches
        }()
        page++
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

How can I break the loop as soon as there are no more results?

EDIT:
Reason for `for{}`: Shodan return 100 results per page, but I have no way of knowing how many pages of results there are. Thats why I used a `for{}` loop, and was hoping to break from the loop as soon as there are no more values (meaning no more pages). `page`, together with the following code:

```
matches, _ := shodanClient.GetHostsForQuery(&shodan.HostQueryOptions{
                Query: "country:AL port:8080 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' 'http server 1.0'",
                Page: page,
            })
```

Should fire off a request to the shodan API to the specific page. This is also why I would like concurrency.

Comment: Why is this in a `for{}` loop? That's why it's running forever, you've told it explicitly to loop forever.

Comment: You're dispatching an infinite number of goroutines as fast as your system can schedule them. You also have a data race around `page`, so the value you're requesting is meaningless. What is the goal here with concurrency?

Comment: @JimB please see the edit.

Comment: @rhillhouse: if you don't know how many results there will be until you make each request, you can't very well make them concurrently.